# Mercurial: clone only a branch of a repository

Tags: mercurial

in my mercurial project I have some users that can clone the repository, but I need that they only can see some branches.

For example they can see only the "stable" branch so I can be sure they will never try unstable code. 
Or customer X can see only the branch with his customizations.

I know I can extract the source code of the release and give it to them. But for "non technical" reasons they want access to the repository.

Is it possible?

Thanks,
Mario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ACL extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AclExtension), in which you define `[acl.deny.branches]` and `[acl.allow.branches]`.

The following sample config is taken from the ACL documentation page.

```
  [hooks]

  # Use this if you want to check access restrictions at commit time
  pretxncommit.acl = python:hgext.acl.hook

  # Use this if you want to check access restrictions for pull, push,
  # bundle and serve.
  pretxnchangegroup.acl = python:hgext.acl.hook

  [acl]
  # Check whether the source of incoming changes is in this list where
  # "serve" == ssh or http, and "push", "pull" and "bundle" are the
  # corresponding hg commands.
  sources = serve

  [acl.groups]
  # If a group name is not defined here, and Mercurial is running under
  # a Unix-like system, the list of users will be taken from the OS.
  # Otherwise, an exception will be raised.
  designers = user1, user2

  [acl.deny.branches] 

  # Everyone is denied to the frozen branch: 
  frozen-branch = * 

  # A bad user is denied on all branches: 
  * = bad-user 

  [acl.allow.branches] 

  # A few users are allowed on branch-a: 
  branch-a = user-1, user-2, user-3 

  # Only one user is allowed on branch-b: 
  branch-b = user-1 

  # The super user is allowed on any branch: 
  * = super-user 

  # Everyone is allowed on branch-for-tests: 
  branch-for-tests = *
```